# Creating Magento Bundled or Group Products with Configurable Products

Tags: magento, configurable-product

Is there a way to create a bundled product or group product in Magento Community with pictures and configurable products. The client sells Auto Floor mats and in any set there are front row floor mats and back row floor mats, each has their own color option.

we need to display the image of the two portions of the set and allow the user to select the color. So if someone would like to buy the set, and for what ever reason would like black mats in the front and tan mats in the back, the option would be available to them.

Does anyone know if bundled or group does this function, or if there is a plugin that does this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this :

1. Create a **bundled product** named "*Auto Floor Mats Set*".
2. Create **4 configurable products** named :

   - "*Front-Left Mat*"
   - "*Front-Right Mat*"
   - "*Back-Left Mat*"
   - "*Back-Right Mat*"

   then
3. Create **3 simple products** for each configurable product and associate them with configurable products created in previous step ( e.g. create simple products named :

   - "*Red Front-Left Mat*"
   - "*Green Front-Left Mat*"
   - "*Blue Front-Left Mat*"

   and associate them with configurable product "*Front-Left Mat*")
4. In your bundled product, go to "*Bundle items" -> "Add New Option*" and **create 4 options** :

   - "*Front-Left*"
   - "*Front-Right*"
   - "*Back-Left*"
   - "*Back-Right*"

   and **add 3 selections** for each option. e.g. add simple products :

   - "*Red Front-Left Mat*"
   - "*Green Front-Left Mat*"
   - "*Blue Front-Left Mat*"

   as selections for option "*Front-Left Mat*".

That's all !

---

Tested on Magento Community 1.7.0.2

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I am not sure what happened when I posted this but I completely forgot to get back to it. This is great! Can you tell me if there is a way to add pictures to those configurable/ simple product options?

Comment: This works for products that are configurable on one attribute.  If a configurable product has more than one configurable attribute (e.g. size & color), then this solution will not work.